# import statement not working in JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I am a new programmer, recently I started coding in react but I have this problem with my JavaScript code. Import is not working.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { hello } from '/components/hello.js';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>
      <p>
        <hello></hello>
      </p>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This here is my app.js file

```
import React from 'react';

export default function hello(){
    return <h1>Hello user</h1>;
}
```

This here is my hello.js file(It is located inside my components folder)
Can anyone tell me why import is not working??

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
    import React from 'react';

    export default function Hello(){
    return <h1>Hello user</h1>;
}
```

To this:

```
    import React from 'react';

    export function Hello(){
    return <h1>Hello user</h1>;
}
```

If you want to leave it as a default function then import it like this instead:

```
import Hello from '/components/Hello.js';
```

Also, it is best practice to capitalize component names. `<Hello />`

Answer (score 1):

Try using default import instead of name import because in your hello.js you are setting up for default. Also your path for hello.js is right? Try ./hello.js